# "ORA-03146: invalid buffer length for TTC field" after upgrade from Oracle 12 to 19c

Tags: c#, database, oracle, unmanaged

We are experiencing problems with updating a table record BLOB column. We get the "ORA-03146: invalid buffer length for TTC field" error. We basically are saving e.g. PDF attachments to the DB.
The problem occurred after the upgrade from Oracle 12.0.1.2 to 19c (19.3.0.0), now the error is occurring on a larger scale.
We have a .Net application, connecting to Oracle through ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAccess) and using NHibernate.
We have done an upgrade from Oracle 12.1.0.2 to Oracle 19.3.0.0 using DBUA and the DB server is on Windows 2012 platform.

The error occurs after executing the command:
{OpsSqlPrepare2(): SQL: UPDATE SIRIUS.Attachment SET Request = :p0, LOANREQUEST = :p1, ARCHIVE = :p2, FILENAME = :p3, FILESIZE = :p4, BINARYCONTENT = :p5, ATTACHMENTTABLE = :p6, ATTACHMENTTYPE = :p7, NOTE = :p8, MIMETYPE = :p9, CUSTOMID = :p10, ISEXTERNAL = :p11, ISSEND = :p12, DocumentNameDial = :p13, DOCUMENTENUMTYPE = :p14, AttachmentTypeDial = :p15 WHERE ID = :p16}

BINARYCONTENT is a BLOB column.

The error is different from the two environments we have:

- Oracle DB 19c/Oracle client 19c - ORA-03146: invalid buffer length for TTC field
- Oracle DB 19c/Oracle client 12 - ORA-03138: Connection terminated due to security policy violation

Comment: http://ora.codes/ora-03146/ ?

Comment: Looks like indeed there is a problem, but does not look like code related, I wonder if this is the best site to ask. Maybe at [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Hello, thanks for suggestions. I alreadz contacted Oracle support, but it seems to be going nowhere. The error seems to be evironment specific, So I posted mz question here hoping someone had at least similar issue. I will also try to post the question on Database Administrators page.

Comment: The first error I found reference saying the default type is wrong.  See : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05730_.htm